# "MSXML2" has no member "IXMLDOMNode" problem in VC++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, atl, msxml

I'm trying to compile a VC++ project I've inherited that uses MSXML2. This is an ATL .EXE project. A header file includes the following:

```
#include "msxml2.h"

using namespace MSXML2;
```

Preprocessor definitions include __USE_MSXML2_NAMESPACE__, which I added to the project because without it the MSXML2 namespace was undefined. Attempting to build this project I receive many errors of the form:

**error C2039: 'IXMLDOMNode' : is not a member of 'MSXML2'**

These errors are produced by declarations like the following

```
CComPtr<MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode> pNode;
```

Other members are not found, including IXMLDOMDocument and IXMLDOMNode.

Comment: Can you include msxml2.h, remove __USE_MSXML2_NAMESPACE__ and using namespace MSXML2, and use CComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> pNode;? That should work.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed worked, can you give me a brief explanation what was going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this

1. Include `msxml2.h` header.
2. Remove `USE_MSXML2_NAMESPACE` and `using namespace MSXML2` code.
3. Use `CComPtr<IXMLDOMNode> pNode;` without namespace.

I've seen many projects using import keyword to ask Visual C++ to generate the header file from TBL using MSXML2 namespace. However, using header and linking to lib is my favorite way to avoid using import keyword as it is not c++ standard. The bottom line is to avoid mixing the two approaches when refreshing old projects, which will lead to problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, problem fixed and project compiling now! I have to say, removing both the 'using' statement and the 'MSXML2::' qualifier seems counterintuitive to me, but with a deadline looming I'm not complaining.